# Elastic Search scaled float not accepting data

Tags: elasticsearch

Following is the mapping for the index **index_new**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "age": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "price_amount": {
                    "properties": {
                        "val": {
                            "type": "scaled_float",
                            "scaling_factor": 100
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While adding the data to this index

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:9200/new_index1/1 \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
     "title":    "new data for index",
        "name":     "balakarthik",
        "age":      24,
        "price_amount": {
            "val": 1005,
            "scaling_factor": 100   
        }

}'
```

this returns an error

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "failed to parse"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Field [val] misses required parameter [scaling_factor]"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

As the scaling factor is already provided in the mapping do we need to send the scaling factor in each requests, if so then how we need to send the scaling factor in each requests.

Definition for scaled_float is available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/number.html#_which_type_should_i_use)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error but got past it by changing the URL.

Your PUT should go to:  http://localhost:9200/new_index1/_doc/1

Also, you should change your input data to only specify the value.  Something like this:

```
{
  "title": "new data for index",
  "name": "balakarthik",
  "age": 24,
  "price_amount": 10.05
}
```